# слайдер с миниатюрами внизу и сбоку

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slider

Исходные данные: есть стандартный слайдер с большой(выбранной) картинкой по центру и миниатюрами под ней расположенных в строку. Нужно сделать так, чтобы миниатюры, находящиеся внизу, встали прямым углом(желательно не разделять их в HTML).
Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли готовые решения для такого вида слайдера, или как подобное реализовать на css/js(в каком направлении двигаться, хотя бы).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это Вам, как отправная точка. Разбирайтесь. Я оставил простор для творчества.

```js
var oViewImage = document.querySelector('.view_image');
var aImages = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.main_wraper > img'));
var aArrow = document.querySelectorAll('.view_wraper > a');

aImages.forEach(function(item, index) {
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    oViewImage.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + this.src + ')';
    if (oSel = document.querySelector('.thumb-select')) {
      oSel.classList.remove('thumb-select')
    };
    this.classList.add('thumb-select');
    aArrow[0].classList.remove('thumb-hide');
    aArrow[1].classList.remove('thumb-hide');
    if (index == 0) {
      aArrow[0].classList.add('thumb-hide');
    }
    if (index == aImages.length - 1) {
      aArrow[1].classList.add('thumb-hide');
    }
  });
});

aArrow[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  let i = aImages.length;
  while (i--) {
    if (aImages[i].classList.contains('thumb-select')) break;
  }
  if (i > 0) {
    aImages[i - 1].dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
    if (aImages[i - 1].classList.contains('thumb-hide')) {
      aImages[i - 1].classList.remove('thumb-hide');
    }
  }
});

aArrow[1].addEventListener('click', function() {
  let i = aImages.length;
  while (i--) {
    if (aImages[i].classList.contains('thumb-select')) break;
  }
  if (i < aImages.length - 1) {
    aImages[i + 1].dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
    if (i + 1 > 7) {
      aImages[i - 7].classList.add('thumb-hide');
    }
  }
});

aArrow[1].dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```

```css
:root {
  --main-color: #333;
  --main-width: 600px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main_wraper {
  background: var(--main-color);
  height: calc(var(--main-width) / 1.75);
  margin: 20px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: var(--main-width);
}

.main_wraper>img {
  background: radial-gradient(#fff, var(--main-color));
  float: left;
  height: 25%;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  width: 20%;
}

.main_wraper>img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.view_wraper {
  background: radial-gradient(#fff, var(--main-color));
  float: right;
  height: 75%;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 80%;
}

.view_image {
  background: transparent no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.thumb-select {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  opacity: .2;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.thumb-hide {
  display: none;
}

.arrow_wrap {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  border: 4px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 1px 4px 20px -5px #000 inset;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  cursor: pointer;
  font: 24px/32px 'Arial';
  height: 40px;
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  top: 50%;
  user-select: none;
  width: 40px;
}

.arrow_wrap:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  text-shadow: 1px 2px 6px #000;
}

.arrow_wrap:active {
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
}

.arrow-rew {
  left: 20px;
}

.arrow-fwd {
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_wraper">
  <div class="view_wraper">
    <div class="view_image"></div>
    <a href="#" class="arrow_wrap arrow-rew">&#9668;&nbsp;</a>
    <a href="#" class="arrow_wrap arrow-fwd">&nbsp;&#9658;</a>
  </div>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/160x120/ffaaaa/ffffff?text=1" alt="">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/160x120/ffcc66/ffffff?text=2" alt="">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/160x120/00CED1/444444?text=3" alt="">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/160x120/66bb66/ffffff?text=4" alt="">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/160x120/6666bb/ffffff?text=5" alt="">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/160x120/ffaaaa/ffffff?text=6" alt="">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/160x120/ffcc66/ffffff?text=7" alt="">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/160x120/00CED1/444444?text=8" alt="">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/160x120/66bb66/ffffff?text=9" alt="">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/160x120/6666bb/ffffff?text=10" alt="">
</div>
```

Изображений можно добавить сколько угодно. И, желательно, уже отформатированных с нужными пропорциями.